# Is req.referer secure?

Tags: node.js, http, authentication

I have some middleware that only calls `next()` if `req.referer` is a certain value.

Can a client somehow alter the value that will be assigned to `req.referer`?

The goal of the middleware is to protect static assets.  Static assets can only be requested by authenticated users, and once authenticated, the user will be redirected such that the value of `req.referer` will "pass" the middleware check.

Is this safe? If not, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client can alter it very easily.

You should never trust the Referer header like you should never trust any data provided by the client.

Instead of relying on the Referer header you should check a token in the cookie or add some token into the URL as part of the path or as a query parameter.

For example, to every link in the form:

```
http://www.example.com/path/file.pdf
```

you could a token:

```
http://www.example.com/path/file.pdf?token=XXX
```

where XXX would be something signed by your server that could include the user, expiration date of the token, scope of usage etc. That way you could have finer grained control than just jecking whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize that cookies are sent on every request.  That would totally work for me.