# Securing access to a video content hosted in Amazon S3 by creating an access policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it secure to host a video content for an LMS system on amazon s3 and then creating an access policy for only allowing a particular website to access the content, while the content link will be posted on the website by hotlinking or embedding the link.

The access policy is like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PreventHotlinking",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ObjectName/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "https://example.com/*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem with this method is that for using it first we have to make the S3 bucket publicly available and after that this access policy works but I somehow doubt that it is not fully secure.

Is there a better method for securing the content?

Answer (score 2):

No. `Referer` is not a secure method of protecting private content. It can easily be spoofed by adding a header to a web request.

See: [Referer spoofing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing)

To make it more secure, a token can be passed between applications to prove authority.

See:

- [Is HTTP REFERER safe enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23955679/174777)
- [Is req.referer secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43072930/174777)
- [Securing HTTP referer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44180563/174777)